# How can I convert a String with \xf6 chars into a human readable one?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, iconv

Currently I'm working on an Rails application with PayPal checkout. PayPal communicates with my app with IPN messages.

In many cases everything works fine, but if someone uses special chars like German umlauts (`öüäß`) I get `\xf6` in the string.

How can I convert this into the human readable char `'ö'`?

Comment: What is the full string (with the `\xf6`) returned to you? (Assuming it is returned as a string; otherwise are you reading it from a file or something?)

Comment: The IPN is a POST request to the server. The payload I get with parameters. For example I can get the payers name with params[:last_name]. And in my case it says "Sch\xF6ning" instead if Schöning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the data was encoded as Windows-1252, but ruby won't detect that automatically.  You can coax it like this:

```
my_string = "Sch\xF6ning"
my_string.force_encoding('windows-1252').encode('utf-8')
=> "Schöning"
```

You can make a reusable converter to help you do the same thing:

```
ec = Encoding::Converter('windows-1252', 'utf-8')
ec.convert(my_string)
=> "Schöning"
```

Comment: Good answer, but iso-8859-1 is latin-1. Windows-1252 is a different encoding.

Comment: @pguardiario: You are correct - it is [the basis for Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but they are not identical.  Windows-28591 is actually the page that matches the ISO spec - corrected.

Comment: @PinnyM: Why have you changed your answer? You were right. The encoding was windows-1252 and your code worked for me verry well.

Comment: @DimitriRoschkowski: [HTTP standard encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.4.1) for 'text/*' is ISO-8859-1, not Windows-1252.  The HTML5 spec complicates this by stating that documents claiming to use ISO-8859-1 should actually be parsed out using Windows-1252. The answer given works for ISO-8859-1 and will work for Windows-1252 as well for _most cases_ (including German), but not necessarily for all (notably French).  However, if you are absolutely sure it is using Windows-1252, then simply use 'windows-1252' in its place.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 may be the HTTP standard encoding, but PayPal uses Windows-1252. I don't have a clue why. In the IPN (instand payment notification) the type of encoding is a part of the notification and one variable of it says "charset"=>"windows-1252"

Comment: @DimitriRoschkowski, updated answer accordingly.  The principal remains the same in any case...

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a setup on paypal side for that:

In the seller paypal account go to : Profile > My selling tools > PayPal button language encoding > More options